# Getting error while sending email(SSL is enabled)

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, spring-security

I want to implement registration functionality - which uses email verification. Previously I was getting SSL error(as SSL was not enabled), then I enabled it as well as generated and added required certificates.
Now I am getting below error while sending a verification email for registration.

```
Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@43c8a994:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@517ab7e5:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:8080 remote=/127.0.0.1:60431]], Read from buffer: [0]
2021-08-08 21:10:14.432 DEBUG 7828 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:682)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1255)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:794)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

application.properties

```
site.base.url.https=https://localhost:8080/JourneyFood

########## SMTP configuration to send out emails ##########
####### Make sure to use the correct SMTP configurations #######
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=449
spring.mail.username=email@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true

########### SSL Configuration ##########
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/ebininfosoft-ssl-key.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
security.require-ssl=true
```

HomeController

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
     private static final String REDIRECT_LOGIN= "redirect:/login";
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(final Model model) {
        LOGGER.trace("HomeController register method - Entered");
        model.addAttribute("user", new UserSignUpFormData());
        LOGGER.trace("HomeController register method - Exit");
        return "register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")//Post operation
    public ModelAndView register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")UserSignUpFormData user, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("register", "user", user);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return mav;
        }
        else {
            try {
                userService.register(user);
            }catch (Exception e){
                if(e instanceof UserAlreadyExistException)  mav.addObject("message", "An account with this email already exists.");
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
                return mav;
            }
           return new ModelAndView("signup-success", "user", user);
        }
    }
    
    /*
     * @GetMapping("/verify") public String
     * registrationVerification(@RequestParam(required = false) String token, final
     * Model model, RedirectAttributes redirAttr){ if(StringUtils.isEmpty(token)){
     * redirAttr.addFlashAttribute("tokenError",
     * messageSource.getMessage("user.registration.verification.missing.token",
     * null,LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())); return REDIRECT_LOGIN; } try {
     * userService.verifyUser(token); } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
     * redirAttr.addFlashAttribute("tokenError",
     * messageSource.getMessage("user.registration.verification.invalid.token",
     * null,LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())); return REDIRECT_LOGIN; }
     * redirAttr.addFlashAttribute("verifiedAccountMsg",
     * messageSource.getMessage("user.registration.verification.success",
     * null,LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())); return REDIRECT_LOGIN; }
     */
    
    @GetMapping("/verify")
    public ModelAndView verify(@Param("token") String token, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("verify", "user", token);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return mav;
        }else {
            try {
                if (userService.verifyUser(token))
                    return new ModelAndView("verify_success", "user", "Verification Succeeded");
                else
                    return new ModelAndView("verify_fail", "user", "Verification Failed");
            } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
                return new ModelAndView("verify_fail", "user", "Verification Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

UserService

```
@Service("UserService")
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private PrivilegeRepository privilegeRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private SecureTokenService secureTokenService;

    @Autowired
    SecureTokenRepository secureTokenRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;

    @Value("${site.base.url.https}")
    private String baseURL;
    
    @Override
    public UserEntity register(UserSignUpFormData user) throws UserAlreadyExistException, MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        if(checkIfUserExist(user.getEmail())) {
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------User already exists");
            throw new  UserAlreadyExistException("User already exists for this email :"+user.getEmail());
        }
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setContactNoOfGuide(user.getContactNoOfGuide());
        userEntity.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userEntity.setEnabled(true);
        userEntity.setNameOfCenter(user.getNameOfCenter());
        userEntity.setNameOfGuide(user.getNameOfGuide());
        final Role userRole =  createRoleIfNotFound("ROLE_USER", assignPrivilege(userEntity));
        encodePassword(userEntity, user);
        userEntity.setRoles(Arrays.asList(userRole));
        sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(userEntity);
        return userRepository.save(userEntity);
    }
        private void sendRegistrationConfirmationEmail(UserEntity user) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String toAddress = user.getEmail();
        String fromAddress = "email@gmail.com";
        String senderName = user.getNameOfGuide();
        String subject = "Please verify your registration";
        String content = "Dear [[name]],<br>"
                + "Please click the link below to verify your registration:<br>"
                + "<h3><a href=\"[[URL]]\" target=\"_self\">VERIFY</a></h3>"
                + "Thank you,<br>"
                + "Your company name.";
        SecureToken secureToken= secureTokenService.createSecureToken();
        secureToken.setUser(user);
        secureTokenRepository.save(secureToken);
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        helper.setFrom(fromAddress, senderName);
        helper.setTo(toAddress);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        content = content.replace("[[name]]", user.getNameOfGuide());
        String verifyURL = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseURL).path("/verify").queryParam("token", secureToken.getToken()).toUriString();
        content = content.replace("[[URL]]", verifyURL);
        helper.setText(content, true);
        mailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Email has been sent");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verifyUser(String token) throws InvalidTokenException {
        SecureToken secureToken = secureTokenService.findByToken(token);
        if(java.util.Objects.isNull(secureToken)||!StringUtils.equals(token, secureToken.getToken()) || secureToken.isExpired()) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException("Token is not valid");
        }
        UserEntity user = userRepository.getOne(secureToken.getUser().getId());
        if(Objects.isNull(user)) {
            return false;
        }
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
        secureTokenService.removeToken(secureToken);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Self signed certificate location is same as mentioned in application.properties.

Thanks and regards

Comment: You're missing a comma after your second virtual column, before M_MAIL. So where the error message is pointing, really.

Answer (score 3):

Add the comma after line 7 `HH24:MI:SS'))`*,* and you should be fine

```
 7  M_TIME date generated always as (to_CHAR(M_DATE_HH_MM,'HH24:MI:SS')) , 
                                                                        / \
                                                                         |
 8  M_EMAIL VARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MEMBER(M_EMAIL),
```